# What does "greatest" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

> The standard is consistent with ILO Convention 138, or under the legal
>   minimum age for employment in the country, whichever is greatest.

The above example is about child labor. Does "whichever is greatest" mean "the higher age is applied"? Or does this mean "more strict rule is applied (which means that the lower age is applied)"?

I think there were some instances where great/greater means strict/stricter in legal documents. Is this the case?

Comment: What's the source of that sentence?  It doesn't make much sense.  The standard is "under the legal minimum"?  That would make it illegal.

Comment: We don't have the full context, but I'd assume we're talking about some company's minimum standards as regards the age of "child labourers" they're prepared to employ. Presumably ILO Convention 138 sets some limit (anyone under this age is a child, and should be at school, not at work). But for any given country in which the company operates, there might be a *national* law that applies. The company is just saying they'll always adopt the ***higher*** of those two minimum ages, if they're different.

Comment: This is a very poorly constructed sentence, but they are trying to say that the "standard" essentially uses the maximum of two different ages:  the age found in "ILO Convention 138" and the "legal minimum age for imployment in the country".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @BadZen's assessment that this is a very badly constructed sentence, to the point that it's actually not even grammatically correct (or at least if it is interpreted according to the standard rules for grammar, it makes no sense, so the only way to make it make sense is to ignore grammar).

The simple answer to your main question is:  In casual speech, *great* or *greatest* can often refer to "best" or "strongest", but in more formal writing (such as legal documents, which this appears to be or is similar to), *greatest* almost always has a much narrower meaning of simply "largest".  It therefore is generally only used to compare quantities, sizes, or numbers.

Therefore, one wouldn't generally say one rule or principle is "greater" than another.  Given this, it's fairly safe to assume that the two things being compared here are the (numerical) ages in the two rules, and that we should choose the *age* that is *largest* (greatest).

This would have been a lot clearer if the example sentence didn't make the mistake of mixing up its subjects, and then on top of that make the mistake of ending up comparing two uncomparable things.  If we break down that sentence, what is actually written is:

> The standard is consistent with ILO Convention 138

-or-

> The standard is under the legal minimum age for employment in the country

and we should choose one of those options, based on

> whichever *(of the things the standard is supposed to be)* is greatest.

The first bit there ("the standard is consistent ...") actually seems just fine, but then applying the same subject to the second part of the sentence results in "the standard is under the minimum legal age", which makes no sense (a standard can't be above or below an age).  We are then asked to choose which is "greatest" between "ILO Convention 138" and "the legal minimum age", but those two things aren't really comparable in any way (one is a rule and the other is an age).

However, based on the fact that "greatest" was used, and that one of the two is an age (which works with "greatest" in this context, while "ILO Convention 138" doesn't) and presuming that "ILO Convention 138" also has something to do with specifying a minimum age for people), the logical conclusion is that they actually meant the first part of the sentence to actually be talking about the *age* mentioned in "ILO Convention 138", and what they should have said was something more like:

> The **age dictated by the** standard is consistent with **the age specified in** ILO Convention 138, or the legal minimum age for employment in the country, whichever is greatest.